# Suppress CLI terminal output on IOS

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cli

I would like to know if we can suppress certain lines from being displayed on the CLI. Example: I call following TCL script, that in itself calls some other scripts. What i Get on the screen is this:

```
switch#tclsh tftp://172.16.1.1/aliasmenu.tcl cpu
Loading aliasmenu.tcl from 172.16.222.89 (via Vlan10): !
[OK - 7140 bytes]
Calling second script
Loading aliascpu.tcl from 172.16.1.1 (via Vlan10): !
[OK - 198 bytes]
The argument given was cpu
```

What i'd like to see is just this:

```
switch#tclsh tftp://172.16.1.1/aliasmenu.tcl cpu
Calling second script
The argument given was cpu
```

So im looking for a way to suppres the **Loading** commands to the SSH VTY terminal output. I already tried with some discriminator commands:

```
logging discriminator HIDETCL msg-body drops Loading    
logging buffered discriminator HIDETCL
logging console discriminator HIDETCL
logging monitor discriminator HIDETCL
```

But they only work for Log messages. The **Loading** commands aren't log messages but direct outputs to the CLI. I tried the `file prompt quiet` command as well, as i thought maybe the copy command is behind the TCLsh command. But without any luck. Anyone else maybe had to deal with this type of request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do what i wanted with a TCL script, that is sitting on the local flash storage. If i give a command, it will try to download a TCL script with the same name from the TFTP Server and does not show the "loading" part in the CLI. This is the local script:

```
set proto "http://"
set host "172.16.20.5"
set path "/alias/"
set filename "help"
set extension ".tcl"
set remotepath "$proto$host$path$filename$extension"
set localpath "flash:$filename$extension"

if {$argc == "0"} {
        exec "copy $remotepath $localpath"
        source $localpath
        workload $argc $argv
        exec "delete $localpath"
} else {
        set filename [lindex $argv 0]
        set fakefilename "fake"
        set remotepath "$proto$host$path$filename$extension"
        set localpath "flash:$filename$extension"
        set remotefakepath "$proto$host$path$fakefilename$extension"
        set localfakepath "flash:$fakefilename$extension"
        set fakecopy [exec "copy $remotefakepath $localfakepath"]
        set copyresult [exec "copy $remotepath $localpath"]
        if {[lindex [exec "dir | include _$filename$extension"] 8] == "$filename$extension"} {
                source $localpath
                workload $argc $argv
                exec "delete /force $localpath"
        } else {
                puts "Command $argv not found. Use 'get help' for a list of available commands."
        }
}
```

On the Switch, there is following configuration:

```
alias exec get tclsh flash:alias.tcl
```

So if I enter

> get cpu

the script tries to download http://172.16.20.5/alias/cpu.tcl and run it. So i can have a very short script deployed on all devices, but can still modify and deploy new scripts centrally.

Comment: One thing to note about this alias TCL script environment. You need to have `file prompt quiet` configured on the devices in order for them to run smooth. If you dont have the line, the scripts will freeze as they are waiting for user input for copy/delete operations in the flash.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know if we can suppress certain lines from being displayed on the CLI.

Your most basic problem is that you're trying to drop *non-logging messages* with a logging command.

You can't make these messages disappear because they are not considered logging messages:

```
Loading aliasmenu.tcl from 172.16.222.89 (via Vlan10): !
[OK - 7140 bytes]
```

Consider looking at the output of `show log` and you'll discover that the lines above are never added to the logging buffer.

Comment: Well, thats what i wrote myself in the post already: `But they only work for Log messages. The Loading commands aren't log messages but direct outputs to the CLI` I just added these commands to prevent people from suggesting i should use logging discriminators. I guess what you wanna say with your post is: it cannot be done.

Comment: If they are not supposed to work it’s pointless to put them in the question.  You can’t turn those messages off and I still don’t understand why anybody would care.  Even when automating the CLI output it’s easy to ignore them